# How to update UI using setState() from one Stateful Widget to another StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an `AppBar()` that is inside a drawer menu which calls all the pages in my app, (I'm currently using this dependency - https://pub.dev/packages/drawerbehavior)

```
void main() => runApp(NavigatorMenu());

class NavigatorMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigatorMenuState createState() => _NavigatorMenuState();
}

class _NavigatorMenuState extends State<NavigatorMenu> {
   int selectedNavigatorMenuItemId;
      DrawerScaffoldController controller = DrawerScaffoldController();
     
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DrawerScaffold(
          controller: controller,
          appBar: AppBar
            actions: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(pointsText.toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          drawers: [
            SideDrawer(
              percentage: 0.6,
              menu: menu,
              selectedItemId: selectedNavigatorMenuItemId,
              onMenuItemSelected: (itemId) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedNavigatorMenuItemId = itemId;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
          builder: (context, id) => IndexedStack(index: id, children: <Widget>[
            Home(),
          ]),
        );
      }
}
```

I want to update the `pointsText` that is defined globally in my `Home()` but as the `AppBar` is defined in another `StatefulWidget` it wouldn't update the UI of my app.

```
int pointsText;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    pointsText++;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Update UI'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: from where you are using NavigatorMenu() widget

Comment: It is called in the void main() of my app, i'll update my question @jitsm555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare function in `_NavigatorMenuState` which received value from Home Widget

```
  int appBarValue;
  void updateAppBar(int value) {
                setState(() {
                      appBarValue = value;
                  });
  }
```

pass this method to the home widget

```
Home(updateAppBar),
```

Use appBarValue value in `AppBar` Text

```
Text(appBarValue.toString()),
```

finally, give it callback from homescreen.

```
int pointsText;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final _updateAppBar;
  Home(this._updateAppBar);


  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    pointsText++;
                    widget._updateAppBar(pointsText);
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Update UI'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not rebuilding my appBar

Comment: updated the code, just add  appBarValue = value; inside setState()